# Magento 2 - Share session and customer data between subdomain and domain through access Token

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, graphql, token

I want to use custom magento checkout on a subdomain eg checkout.example.com. I have developed that one and getting customer data by access tokens. I want to share login information through access token to this subdomain instead of asking users to login again to see their cart details.

I am stuck to share the login between these two subdomain and domain. Can anybody help